# mvc resources tag is not working in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc

my mvc:resources is not working  in spring mvc .

Below is my code.please help me to resolve this issue.I think I have put resource folder in proper place .

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
    
        <bean id="viewResolver"
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
            <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
        </bean>
    
        <context:component-scan
            base-package="com.et.demo.Controllers"></context:component-scan>
    
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
    
        <mvc:annotation-driven />
    </beans>
```

web.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
        xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
        id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    
        <!-- <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list> -->
        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

[please click here to see my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qVN1.png)

please watch my attached image.

Answer (score 0):

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
            xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
            xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
        
            <!-- <welcome-file-list> <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> </welcome-file-list> -->
            <servlet>
                <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
                <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
                <init-param>
                <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
                <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
                </init-param>
            </servlet>
            
            <servlet-mapping>
               <servlet-name>dispatcher-servlet</servlet-name>
               <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
            </servlet-mapping>
            
 </web-app>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
            xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
            xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  
                http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
        
            <mvc:annotation-driven/>
            <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**"/>
            <context:component-scan base-package="com.et.demo.*"/>
            
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
                <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
                <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
            </bean>     
        </beans>
```

I don't see views folder in WEB-INF (referring to your folder structure image). Replace both of configurations with the above.

Comment: i have tried this but not working ...I have posted full updated product structure here.please look into that . https://stackoverflow.com/q/68150480/16320727   @ThivakaW