# static content is not getting loaded in spring mvc resource tag

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using mvc:resources to access my static content . I am using in a proper way and having proper project structure still not able to access the static content.I am new in spring mvc therefore please help me to solve this.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://JAVA.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="/resources/js/global.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="text-align:center;">Hello World!!</h1>
<button onclick="goToSecondPage()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.et.demo.Controllers" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
</beans>
```

I have tried everything but failed to load static content.[please click here to see my project structure.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNI5K.png)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are two `resources` folders in your project structure. Make sure you are putting your resources in the right folder (the direct child of `main` folder). There is no need to add `/resources/` to the path as well, since it is already mapped by your `mvc:resources` mapping.